# .NET Library For Newport ESP301 Motion Controller

Tags: c#, .net, com, serial-port, hardware

I have found this download on the site:

http://www.newport.com/ESP301-Series-3-Axis-Motion-Controller-Driver/771081/1033/info.aspx#tab_Literature

I get an "ESPUSB.dll" library in the VisualBasic samples but when I load that file into a .NET project, I get there error:

A reference to ESPUSB.dll could not be added.  Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

I am trying to control the motion controller from a .NET program.

Can I do this with that library or should I be using the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class to communicate with the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you [read the manual](http://assets.newport.com/webDocuments-EN/images/14294.pdf) on that page.  Typically these instruments connect via USB and appear as a USB-RS232 com port, so yes, you would use the `SerialPort` class for communication via traditional COM/RS-232 or via USB/RS-232.  I assume you're not using the GPIB(IEEE-488) connection.

Whatever that .DLL file is, it probably belongs to the supplied control application from Newport and has nothing to do with actually controlling the device.  Most manufacturers will provide a basic control application with their instrument so you can just plug in and control it with their supplied software.  That .dll most likely is part of their bundled software.  Since you are writing your own software, you do not need it.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks a lot man.  I have already got the software communicating nicely with the hardware using the SerialPort class.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Newport.ESP301.CommandInterface.dll` installed with the ESP301 GUI. It's referenced in the GUI Manual and the Python example in the Command Interface Manual. The GUI Manual says the DLL installed into the `GAC_32` or `GAC_64` folders. In my case, on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017, it was installed to:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\Newport.ESP301.CommandInterface\v4.0_2.0.0.3__9f994642f5b48132\Newport.ESP301.CommandInterface.dll

I just started using it, so I can't vouch if it's better than rolling your own serial interface, but it does exist.